# Not all threads finishing, maybe due to not locking STDOUT

Tags: multithreading, perl

I am experimenting with threads in perl. The following code basically creates n threads and assigns the same function to them (which they should execute in parallel).

Twist: The function just prints something. This means that they can't do it in parallel. I am honestly fine with that since I am just starting to do things with them however not all threads seem to finish. I suppose it is due to the fact that I haven't locked the STD out and that is why some conficts occur. That may not be the reason. In any case a different ammount of threads are not finishing each time.

If I am correct, how can I lock stdout (I get an error when I try to use the lock function) ?

If I am wrong, why are all threads not finishing and how can I fix that ?

The code:

```
use strict;
use threads ('yield',
                 'stack_size' => 64*4096,
                 'exit' => 'threads_only',
                 'stringify');
use threads::shared;


sub PrintTestMessage()
{
    print "Hello world\n";
}

my @t;
push @t, threads->new(\&PrintTestMessage) for 1..10;
```

I get 10 times hello world, however after the program finishes I get different output:

```
Perl exited with active threads:
    1 running and unjoined
    9 finished and unjoined
    0 running and detached
Perl exited with active threads:
    8 running and unjoined
    2 finished and unjoined
    0 running and detached
Perl exited with active threads:
    5 running and unjoined
    5 finished and unjoined
    0 running and detached
```

Why haven't all threads finished ? ( the unjoined is because I never join them in the code so it is expected)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to join the threads, otherwise main thread could (as in your example) finish before its child threads,

```
$_->join for @t;
```

From [`perldoc threads`](http://perldoc.perl.org/threads.html),

> *$thr->join()*
>
> This will wait for the corresponding thread to complete its execution. When the thread finishes, ->join() will return the return value(s) of the entry point function.

Comment: Or `$_->join for threads->list();`. No need to build an array.